# Performance Counter for tracking 503 - Server Unavailable from IIS

Tags: iis, 503-error, performance-counters

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Service running on IIS 6.0.  I am trying to locate the appropriate Performance Counter to track 503 responses.  I have limited "Web site connections" to 1 for testing purposes and have verified in my client that I am receiving a 503 - Server Unavailable.

According to Microsoft's documentation the ASP.NET\Requests Rejected counter specifically tracks 503 responses.  I am not seeing this at all.

I have tried the following counters (all with scale set to 1 in the Performance graph) and none of them show any activity:

- `ASP.NET\Requests Rejected`
- `ASP.NET v4.0.30319\Requests Rejected`
- `ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319\Requests Rejected`
- `Active Server Pages\Requests Rejected`
- `ASP.NET Applications\Requests Rejected`

I have verified that other counters are tracking my web service activity properly (Web Service\Bytes Total/sec, ASP.NET Applications\Request Execution Time, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limiting the "Web site connections" in IIS Manager keeps the requests from ever getting to ASP.NET and getting logged.  I had to edit `maxWorkerThreads` and `requestQueueLimit` within the machine.config file for the 503 errors to show up under the counter `ASP.NET\Requests Rejected`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a new app pool with a custom identity?  If so, make sure that your app pool identity is added to the IIS_WPG group.  Otherwise it will throw the error you mentioned.  It fails before it can log too, so that's consistent with your summary.

If it's not that, then test a test.html page to find out if it's .net related to app pool related.

Comment: The identity being used is in the IIS_WPG group.  Could you elaborate on how i would test using a static page?

Comment: If you create a simple page called test.html and in the body just put "This is a test".  Does that work?  Whether or not that works will help determine if the issue is with the app pool as a whole, or just asp.net.